# Brachistochrone With Friction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

By using the Euler-Lagrange Equation how do you solve the following functional?

> [Brachistochrone functional taking friction into consideration](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html):
> $$\large t=\int_a^b \sqrt{\frac{({y'}^2+1)}{2g(y-\mu x)}}~dx\tag{28}$$
> where $g$ is a constant ($9.81\mathrm{m/s^2}$) and $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction (another constant).

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the Euler-Lagrange equation?

Comment: Related question on Phys.SE:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772853/2451

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been already solved and documented, unfortunately not freely accessible [Brachistochrone with Coulomb friction](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.9976)

N. Ashby, W. E. Brittin, W. F. Love, and W. Wyss,
American Journal of Physics, Volume 43, Issue 10, 1975

*The problem of finding the curve of most rapid descent of a bead sliding along a wire, from one fixed point to another, under the simultaneous influence of gravity and friction, is solved. A remarkable feature of the problem is that the solution can be expressed in closed form, in terms of elementary functions.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).